# TraitCollectionDidChange behaves different for iphone X

Tags: swift, autolayout, landscape-portrait, size-classes

In My case i am changing my layouts of the view depending  on the traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass
Here is my Code snippet .

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
            // 2
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(compactConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(regularConstraints)
            // 3
            socialMediaView.axis = .horizontal
        } else {
            // 4
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(regularConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(compactConstraints)
            socialMediaView.axis = .vertical
        }
    }
```

Every things working as directed in **iphone 7 plus** and **iphone x** in portrait-mode 
[image: Screen_Shot_2018-08-07_at_1.44.54_PM.png]
and in landscape mode i want the rabbit image comes to left side and the stackview of all socialMedias axis will be horizontal
 but in iphone X landscape mode its not  coming while in phone 7 its coming .Check the below screen shots 
[image: Screen_Shot_2018-08-07_at_1.32.02_PM.png]

Comment: what is your question? it's quite unclear

Comment: Have a look, answer is helping : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163539/traitcollection-horizontalsizeclass-reports-compact-on-ios-8-1-regular-on-ios-8

Comment: @BhavinKansagara i have updated my question please check once and let me know it any clarification you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your question and condition, I found a problem in your condition. you should check for the **verticalSizeClass** instead of horizontalSizeClass.

WHEN CHECK FOR HORIZONTAL SIZE CLASS.

**IN PORTRAIT**: All iPhone Devices has compact width, so every time, it will go to else condition and set the view properly.

**IN LANDSCAPE**: All iPhone Plus **(iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 7 Plus and iPhone 8 plus)** Devices has Regular width and All other iPhone **(iPhone 6s, 6SE, iPhone 7 and iPhone 8, iPhone X)** Devices has Compact width, so for all plus devices it will works fine but not for others.

FOR PORTRAIT: 
[image: Portrait]

FOR LANDSCAPE:
[image: Landscape]

For more, read official doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/)

So, update your code to this.

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(compactConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(regularConstraints)
            socialMediaView.axis = .horizontal
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(regularConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(compactConstraints)
            socialMediaView.axis = .vertical
        }
    }
```

Try and share the results.

Comment: thanks yes are right problem was with the if statement so i modified like this

Comment: if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular || traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
            //Constraint activate
        } else {
            // Constraint deactivate
          
        }
    }

Comment: simply using this condition will also works: if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular. Because that verticalSizeClass is helping to check for portrait and landscape for all devices. regular height means portrait and compact height means landscape.